# Java, WebDriver, asserts/exceptions, and UI states

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception

I am writing a test suite using WebDriver in Java. Importantly, the tests are functional tests, not unit tests. Often, the same test case will be run a few times in sequence with different data - for example, "create application" with different names and components for every application.

The test case executon path includes a few dialogs. At each dialog, an error can happen (for example, "component not found"). Currently, my code handles the errors right next to where they happen - for example: (this is a simplified example not a piece of production code, it was not tested, so please pardon trivial mistakes)

```
WebElement component;
try {
    component = componentsDialog.findElement(By.xpath("@class='component' and @componentId = '" + componentId + "']"));
} catch ( NoSuchElementException nse ) {
    log.error("Component not found");
    driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
    stoppedOnError = true;
    return;
}
component.click();
WebElement buttonAdd = 
componentsDialog.findElement(By.className("addbutton"));
buttonAdd.click();
```

This is not very Java-like for error handling. It might be hard to integrate into TestNG if I choose to use that in the future.

But I can't just leave this to the general NoSuchElementException handler for the test case. Most of the time, NoSuchElementException means that the UI has changed (or I made a mistake in the test code). In this case, it means the particular configuration for this instance of the test case is wrong. And that configuration is set by the user. It is a different error and should be reported differently.

So I could just catch the exception and raise another, with the right message... But note the part where the Escape key is pressed. I close the component selection dialog, so that the state of the UI is he same as if the component selection was successful. In the rest of this test case, this particular dialog is not open. So how would the exception handler (at the end of the test case method or in the caller) know what state the UI is currently in and what it needs to do to recover?

(Autodetection is possible but flaky, as it would rely on detecting the presence of some element unique for every possible dialog).

So what do I do here, in order to enable error handling outside of the immediate execution stream? Keep some state tracking variable somewhere? This seems awfully error prone.

I could of course try to switch to the Page Object Model. The model strikes me as very heavyweight, requiring an increase of lines of code by up to an order of magnitude, and only paying off if many diverse test cases use the very same controls. (Typically, in my cases so far different use cases use different UI elements, so I don't understand how the model would pay off).

Perhaps this impression is mistaken. But even if I do use the model, every page is an unrelated object - how do I know which page is actually active at the time? Calling methods of a page when another page is active will only lead to meaningless exceptions (in the absence of complicated detection logic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to write this code, I would write it like this.

```
List<WebElement> component = componentsDialog.findElements(By.xpath("@class='component' and @componentId = '" + componentId + "']"));
if (component.isEmpty())
{
    log.error("Component not found");
    driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
    componentsDialog.findElement(By.className("addbutton")).click();
}
else
{
    component.get(0).click();
}
```

You don't need to (and IMO shouldn't) throw any exceptions here. If you look at [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) it states

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

Oh... and to your comment about page objects. It shouldn't require much extra code... definitely not orders of magnitude more, if done right. What it does get you is better organization, better reuse of code, lessens the maintenance burden, and so on. Putting all your code for a page or dialog into a single class makes it so much easier to update scripts when things change or when a bug needs to be fixed. It will drastically reduce your maintenance effort.

Comment: Change the findElement method to findElements

Comment: To have your example working the same as mine, we'd need to move the last line into the else block. Note the return statement in my example.

Comment: And in real life, the click of the Add button does not end the test case. There are several checks like that in the test case, so I would end up with the last part of it indented pretty far. I use return statements to avoid that.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for the find! Fixed.